# The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm on Laravel 5.8, and I keep getting this error

> The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.

I have this

`APP_KEY=LkZ0Tg3akce***eBABo2QM4VdEyeYWoPY`

I have this in my `config/app.php`

```
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key length you have is very short

Correct key length is 32 characters preceded by `base64:` and followed by a cipher algorithm like this

```
base64:HgtbpB3ovVQQVMuXUKCgxpvkqhJNBwb/C52Gm/OI4gU=
```

Create a new key using artisan

```sh
php artisan key:generate
```

It should create a new proper key

Answer (score 0):

## step: 1

In addition to : `php artisan key:generate`

## step: 2

I also had to run these commands to see the effect.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

no more error ....